# Remove stop words from sentences and pad sentences from a list of lists in the data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there an easy way to remove certain (stop) words from sentences in a list of lists in a dataframe column and (right)-pad them if they have a length less than the maximum length?

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

stopwords = ['the', 'a', 'an']
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'sentence': [[["the", "deer", 'was', 'a', 'tasty', 'meal'], ["the", "girl", 'walks'], ["thanks", "for", "all", "the", "gifts"]]]})
```

```
|    | sentence                                                                                                           |
|---:|:-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  0 | [['the', 'deer', 'was', 'a', 'tasty', 'meal'], ['the', 'girl', 'walks'], ['thanks', 'for', 'all', 'the', 'gifts']] |
```

Expected result:

```py
|    | sentence                            |
|---:|:------------------------------------|
|  0 | ['deer', 'was', 'tasty', 'meal']    |
|  1 | ['girl', 'walks', '<pad>', '<pad>'] |
|  2 | ['thanks', 'for', 'all', 'gifts']   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
x = df['sentence'].explode().reset_index(drop=True).explode().pipe(lambda x: x[~x.isin(stopwords)])
MAX = x.groupby(level=0).agg(len).max()
new_df = x.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop=True).reindex(np.arange(MAX)).fillna('<pad>')).groupby(level=0).agg(list).to_frame()
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
                      sentence
0     [deer, was, tasty, meal]
1  [girl, walks, <pad>, <pad>]
2    [thanks, for, all, gifts]
```

It uses `explode` twice to get the sub arrays all flattened, and then via `pipe` filters out the stop words. Then, we get the length of the longest group, and `reindex` each group to be as long as that. Note the fill value is `<pad>`, but you can change it to whatever you'd like, or even get rid of the `fillna` call altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using reshaping:

```
df2 = (df.explode('sentence')
         .assign(group=lambda d: d.groupby(d.index).cumcount())
         .explode('sentence')
         .loc[lambda d: ~d['sentence'].isin(stopwords)]         # filter words
         .rename_axis('index')
         .assign(idx=lambda d: d.groupby(['index', 'group']).cumcount())
         .set_index(['group', 'idx'], append=True)
         .unstack('group')        # unstack/stack
         .fillna('<pad>')         # to pad
         .stack('group')          # missing words
         .groupby(level=[0, 'group']).agg(list)
         .reset_index('group', drop=True)
      )
```

output:

```
                      sentence
0     [deer, was, tasty, meal]
0  [girl, walks, <pad>, <pad>]
0    [thanks, for, all, gifts]
```

*NB. this solution should also work on multiple input lines:*

```
df = pd.concat([df]*3, ignore_index=True)

#                                             sentence
# 0  [[the, deer, was, a, tasty, meal], [the, girl,...
# 1  [[the, deer, was, a, tasty, meal], [the, girl,...
# 2  [[the, deer, was, a, tasty, meal], [the, girl,...
```

output:

```
                          sentence
index                             
0         [deer, was, tasty, meal]
0      [girl, walks, <pad>, <pad>]
0        [thanks, for, all, gifts]
1         [deer, was, tasty, meal]
1      [girl, walks, <pad>, <pad>]
1        [thanks, for, all, gifts]
2         [deer, was, tasty, meal]
2      [girl, walks, <pad>, <pad>]
2        [thanks, for, all, gifts]
```